# Laravel uploading multiple files and returning list of filename in controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I want to upload multiple files in selecting file option

**HTML:**

```
                     <div class="input-group form-group">
                     <div class="custom-file form-group">
                         <input id="logo" type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control" name="bankfile" accept="application/pdf" required>
                         <label for="logo" class="custom-file-label"></label>
                     </div>
```

AND return list / array of filename in `filename`
**PATH:**
`Http/Controllers/statementController.php`

**CONTROLLER:**

```
           public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try 
        {
            @$bankname = $request->bankname;
            @$password = $request->password;
            @$analytics_id = $request->analytics_id;

            if(@$analytics_id==null)
            {
                @$analytics_id = session('analytics_id');

            }
            
            @$file = $request->file('bankfile');

            function random_strings($length_of_string) 
            { 
                // String of all alphanumeric character 
                $str_result = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; 
                // Shufle the $str_result and returns substring 
                // of specified length 
                return substr(str_shuffle($str_result),0, $length_of_string); 
            } 

            @$job_id = random_strings(20); 

            @$filenamePre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            @$path_parts = pathinfo($filenamePre);
            @$extension =  $path_parts['extension'];
            @$filename=@$analytics_id.'-'.@$bankname.'-'.@$job_id.'.'.$extension;
            
            @$file->move(base_path().'/storage/app/public/bks/case_1/', $filename); 

            // analytics::dispatch($job_id,$analytics_id,$bankname,$filename,$password)->delay(now()->addSeconds(3));

            DB::select('insert into analytics_job set descr=?,analytics_user_id=?',[$job_id,$analytics_id]);
            DB::select('insert into analytics_report set analysis_user_id=?,    job_id=?,filename=?,password=?,bankname=?',[$analytics_id,$job_id,$filename,$password,$bankname]);

            @$data = array('job_id' => @$job_id, 'analytics_id' => @$analytics_id, 'bankname' => @$bankname , 'filename' => @$filename, 'password' => @$password);

            @$result = $this->analyticsData(@$data);
            @$resultJson = json_decode(@$result);
            if(@$resultJson->code==200)
            {

            }

    
            return redirect('/analytics/dashboard');
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Following Error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null
```

Comment: And, what is the problem? Or even question? A mere “I want” is not one. Please go read [ask].

Comment: `$file` is empty/null that is why you're getting this error. Add more of your code on how you are assigning values to `$file`

Comment: @FahadAli Thanks for your response. I have added the whole controller code. I am new in Laravel.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar And can you post your `<form>` as well? I mean have you added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part?

Comment: @FahadAli, No i haven't added in `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in HTML form element. Can you help me out where do i put that attribute.

Comment: @FahadAli, I do have a written javascript variable which has a list of filename upload. Can i use that? If so then how do I put in `filename` in controller.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar are you using JavaScript to submit the form? I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217964/discussion-between-fahad-ali-and-maqsud-inamdar).